# How to resolve a promise within another promise and get the resolution within a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services

I have a function in a service returns a promise. I call this function from a different service where I want to alter the result of the promise and make this new altered value available to my controllers.

```
angular.module('test').service("service1", function($q) {
      function doSomething(something) {    
           //parses some data
           return deferred.promise;
       }

  return {
      doSomething: doSomething
  }
 });

 angular.module('test').service("service2", ['service1', $q, function(service1, $q) {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     var myResult = deferred.promise;      

     service1.doSomething("test").then(function (result) {
         var alteredResult = result + "Altered"; //result I want to be accessible by my controllers
         deferred.resolve(alteredResult)
     });

 return {
      myResult: myResult
  }
}]);


angular.module('test').controller('testController', ['$scope', 'service2', function ($scope, service2) {

      $scope.test = service2.myResult;

}]);
```

It obviously didn’t work when I was initializing `myResult` outside of the `.then()` and updating it inside because `myResult` was passed to the controller before it was altered. This lead me to try creating another promise inside of `service2`.

After all of this, I get a promise in `$scope.test` but it ends up being a blank `{}` javascript object.

How can I properly store the altered result of `service2` so that I can access it from my controllers?

Thanks you very much for your time. Let me know if you need additional information or if I am being unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning promise to the scope variable. You should resolve the promise (promise chain) and assign the resolved value instead.

```
service2.myResult.then(function(result) {
  $scope.test = result;
});
```